# Please explain the steps in the solution of this integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

After unsuccessfully solving an integral, I turned to WRA for some guidance. Unfortunately, I don't understand what happen in the solution. More particularly, I don't understand why the numerator has tan^1x and not tan^2x (see red highlights)

[image]
[Direct Link](http://f.cl.ly/items/3W2M1J2P2v14390j1U0n/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-27%20at%201.45.10%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\dfrac{1}{\sec{u}} = \cos{u}
$$
so substituting everything gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{x^2} \, dx &= \int \dfrac{(\tan(u))}{(\sec(x)/2)^2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \tan(u) \sec(u) \, du \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{4 \tan^2(u) \sec(u)}{\sec(u)^2} \,du\\
&= 2\int \dfrac{\tan^2(u)}{\sec(u)} \,du\\
&= 2\int \tan(u) \cdot \dfrac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)} \cdot\cos(u) \,du\\
&= 2\int \tan(u) \sin(u) \,du.
\end{align*}
$$
The trick is in turning one of the tangents into sine over cosine.